# What is the limit of $\sin^x(x)$?

Tags: calculus

Consider

$ \sin^x(x). $

How could I find the limit of this function as $x$ goes to $0$ or $\infty$?

I tried plotting it at desmos but it didn't work. Any ideas what happens here?

It should converge, however, if you had to graph it, how would it look? Completely random or?

Answer (score 3):

This is either undefined (if you only allow real numbers) or multivalued (if you allow complex numbers) when $\sin x<0$ for most $x$. Either way there's no limit because whenever $\sin x=1$ we have that $\sin^x x=1$, and this happens infinitely often.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using a real valued function, since $\sin x$ takes negative values, the limit at $0$ is only defined from the RHS, which is equal to $1$. The function does not have a limit at $+\infty$ as each $x=\frac{(4n+1)\pi}{2}$ has $\sin x =1$ but $x=n\pi$ has $\sin x=0$.

It does work in Desmos, you just have to include the power of $x$ after the function. This should answer your question about what it looks like. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6rrz0p8fy1

Answer (score 2):

$\sin^x x$ may be undefined for some $x>0$ e.g. $x={3\pi\over 2}$ leads to $(-1)^{3\pi\over 2}$. A same case happens for $x\to 0^-$, but for $x>0$ we obtain $$0<kx<x-{x^3\over 6}<\sin x<1\implies k^xx^x<\sin^x x<1$$for any $0<k<1$. By tending $x\to 0^+$ and using$$\lim_{x\to0^+}x^x=1$$ we obtain $$\lim_{x\to0^+}\sin^x x=1$$

Answer (score 1):

The answers above, but $\sin^x(x)$ does have a limit as $x$ positive and goes to 0:

For $x$ positive and sufficiently small, $x \ge \sin x \ge \frac{x}{2}$. But

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x^x = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} e^{x \ln x} = e^0=1.$$

By similar reasoning

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (x/2)^x = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} e^{x (\ln x-\ln 2)} = 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $a<0$ and $b$ is an arbitrary real, $a^b$ is not defined. Consequently, $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sin^x x$ is not defined either. It should also be noted that $\sin^xx$ equals $0$ whenever $x=k\pi$ and equals $1$ whenever $x=(2k+\frac12)\pi$, which also shows that the limit does not exist.

For $x\to 0$, we again have problems with negative $x$, so we perhaps want to rather investigate
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sin^x x=\lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{x\ln \sin x}$$ for $x\approx 0$, we have $\sin x\approx x$ and thereby 
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}x\ln \sin x=\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\ln x=\lim_{y\to +\infty} e^{-y}\ln e^{-y}=\lim_{y\to+\infty}\frac{-y}{e^y}=0$$
so that 
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sin^x x=1.$$